# Search Mongo Document based on BSON DateTime

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My mongo document looks like below -

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5977dab66ea64e345288ceec"),
"transactionid" : "1",
"servicename" : "Reservation Service",
"starttime" : {
    "dateTime" : true,
    "symbol" : false,
    "javaScriptWithScope" : false,
    "string" : false,
    "regularExpression" : false,
    "javaScript" : false,
    "double" : false,
    "document" : false,
    "DBPointer" : false,
    "number" : false,
    "boolean" : false,
    "null" : false,
    "bsonType" : "DATE_TIME",
    "array" : false,
    "int32" : false,
    "int64" : false,
    "binary" : false,
    "value" : NumberLong(1501026996822),
    "decimal128" : false,
    "objectId" : false,
    "timestamp" : false
},
"endtime" : {
    "dateTime" : true,
    "symbol" : false,
    "javaScriptWithScope" : false,
    "string" : false,
    "regularExpression" : false,
    "javaScript" : false,
    "double" : false,
    "document" : false,
    "DBPointer" : false,
    "number" : false,
    "boolean" : false,
    "null" : false,
    "bsonType" : "DATE_TIME",
    "array" : false,
    "int32" : false,
    "int64" : false,
    "binary" : false,
    "value" : NumberLong(1501026997875),
    "decimal128" : false,
    "objectId" : false,
    "timestamp" : false
},
"status" : "Success",
"updatedby" : "muf",
"requestpayload" : "{\n     \"service_header\": {\n     \t\n    \n     \t\"service_name\": \"Reservation Service\",\n     \t\"source_id\": \"Amex\",\n     \t \t\"document_id\":\"1\",\n     \t\"transaction_id\":\"1\"\n     },\n  \t\n  \t\"airline\":\"united\",\n\t\"destination\":\"LAX\"\n\n\n}",
"responsepayload" : "[{\"departureDate\":\"2015/02/11\",\"airlineName\":\"United\",\"destination\":\"LAX\",\"price\":345.99,\"planeType\":\"Boeing 737\",\"code\":\"ER45if\",\"origin\":\"MUA\",\"emptySeats\":52},{\"departureDate\":\"2015/04/11\",\"airlineName\":\"United\",\"destination\":\"LAX\",\"price\":346.0,\"planeType\":\"Boeing 777\",\"code\":\"ER45jd\",\"origin\":\"MUA\",\"emptySeats\":12},{\"departureDate\":\"2015/06/11\",\"airlineName\":\"United\",\"destination\":\"LAX\",\"price\":423.0,\"planeType\":\"Boeing 707\",\"code\":\"ER0945\",\"origin\":\"MUA\",\"emptySeats\":0}]",
"exception" : "",
"requesthost" : "localhost",
"requestport" : "8086",
"requestpath" : "/flights"
```

}

I am trying to query below document using below query -

```
db.getCollection('Transaction').find({ starttime: { "$gt" : { "$date" : (new ISODate("2018-07-25T23:56:36.822Z")*1) }   }   })
```

I do get the result. However when I try to use less than and greater than together I don't get any result. I am not sure what is best way to query above document.

```
db.getCollection('Transaction').find({ starttime: { "$gt" : { "$date" : (new ISODate("2015-07-25T23:56:36.822Z")*1) } , "$lt" : { "$date" : (new ISODate("2018-07-25T23:56:36.822Z")*1) }    }   })
```

Comment: If your documents look like that then you actually managed to "break your dates" when you recorded them. What code actually wrote these values? That's the largest concern because they are not recorded correctly and should be fixed at the source, before of course correcting the data itself.

Comment: I am inserting data using Mulesoft Connector for Mongo db.

Comment: You should show the code that is doing this, because it's presently incorrect. If these were correct BSON Dates then they would appear just as `ISODate` when viewed in the MongoDB shell or Robo3T tool you seem to be using. The present stored data is the result of bad code.

Comment: I downloaded connector from here - http://mulesoft.github.io/mongo-connector/

Comment: To be clear "the connector is not the problem". Your usage of the connector is what is causing the data to be stored like this. The format shows that clearly it's serializing the internal state of an object rather than converting to the correct storage class, which would be `java.util.Date` from any Java based application. We can tell you "how to fix this data", but unless the source of the writing problem is identified then this will only continue. So "fixing" serves little purpose until the source of the problem is corrected.

Comment: The Mulesoft connector is an ESB module for serializing into MongoDB. Obviously, it does so in a special way. However, the `value` field seems to be msecs since epoch and therefor should be easily comparable.

Comment: How should I compare in my case based on value.